# Strange, garbled formatting on question #154133 'Boot from ISO'

Tags: discussion, bug

I just encountered [the answer to this question](https://superuser.com/questions/154133/grub-boot-from-iso#154204) and curiously enough my browser, for the first time, shows comments entangled with the bottom of the response paragraphs, like this:

[image: Comments overlapping the bottom of the response]

I even can't access any of the edit, share (...) buttons. Is there something that can be done?

FYI my browser is Seamonkey 2.49.5.2 on (Gentoo) Linux and it's the only browser I have on my system so I can't really check anything right now (I'd need another hour or two to compile and check Firefox).

Note: I've just emptied my browser's cache, no change.

Comment: Seems fine in both Chrome and Firefox on Android at least.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/307439/end-of-long-question-or-answer-overprinting-status-information-at-bottom-of-brow seems related, older version of FF too...

Comment: @JourneymanGeek indeed this seems to fall exactly under the same category. I've browsed a few of those links and could notice some extra spacing as well as overlapping areas.

Comment: I just started encountering the same issue on several pages using FF ESR 52.6 which is the current ESR version.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### My browser shows comments entangled with the bottom of the answer

> my browser is Seamonkey 2.49.5.2 on (Gentoo) Linux

Unfortunately you are using an [unsupported browser](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71208/267099):

> We support the last two versions of the browsers that we see the vast
>   majority of our visitors actually use. This does not include beta/dev
>   releases, which are not supported.
>
> The supported browsers, in practice, based on the above guideline:
>
> - Standard View
>
>   - Internet Explorer (current version status from Wikipedia)
>           Compatibility mode should be disabled
>           Exception: Internet Explorer on Mac OS X
>   - Firefox (current version status from Wikipedia)
>   - Chrome (current version status from Wikipedia)
>   - Opera (current version status from Wikipedia)
>   - Safari (current version status from Wikipedia)
>   - Edge (current version status from Wikipedia)
> - Mobile View
>
>   - Android browser
>           Supported: 4.0 and up (source)
>   - Mobile Safari (iPhone browser)
>           Supported: the versions that come with iOS 9 and up.

Comment: Seamonkey's engine is based on Firefox', (from memory) 48 or 52 — given the obsolescence rate nowadays, yeah, I know *sighs*. As a matter of fact I've checked the Acid 3 tests and it ramps up to 98 over 100. Alas the latest version of Seamonkey at this time of writing is 2.49.2. Anyway I'm curious to know what triggers that bug. There has to be something weird going there.

Comment: I've just tested the same page on a Windows machine with Firefox 47 and there's no issue. I start to suspect something weird while compiling Seamonkey on my machine. There's an upgrade pending, I'll check and see how it goes.

Comment: @Nasha For what it's worth I can repro with Seamonkey 2.49.2 on WIndows 7 64 bit.

Comment: Bingo (too)! My Gentoo machine is out of suspicion! I've just loaded that page with the recent version of Seamonkey on a Windows (XP, 32 bits) machine and the same garbling happens. Honour's safe.

Comment: If we're not supporting the current FF ESR version, that could be a problem for a lot of users.